# How to aggregate dataframe by minimum daily value

Tags: r, dataframe, max, aggregate, min

I am trying to extract values in a large data frame (with per minute data) where I want a subset of the data frame when x variable is at its daily minimum and maximum.

For an example data set see below. The example I have given has daily values to reduce the complexity - so in this case how would I get the monthly data frame values when temperature is at its minimum and maximum.

I do not have a great deal of experience in aggregate but I have been able to extract the monthly min and max temp values:

```
a <- as.data.frame(aggregate(df$Temp, df[4], function(x) {
 c(max = max(x), min = min(x)) }))
```

But I am not sure how to do this without losing the information from the original data frame - it would almost be a subset based on a minimum and maximum argument? But I am not sure how to write that.

Any help would be appreciated - and apologies for the large dput example.
Thanks

```
df <- structure(list(Group.1 = c(1628, 1629, 1630, 1631, 1632, 1633, 
1634, 1635, 1636, 1637, 1638, 1639, 1640, 1641, 1642, 1643, 1644, 
1645, 1646, 1647, 1648, 1649, 1650, 1651, 1652, 1653, 1654, 1655, 
1656, 1657, 1658, 1659, 1660, 1661, 1662, 1663, 1664, 1665, 1666, 
1667, 1668, 1669, 1670, 1671, 1672, 1673, 1674, 1675, 1676), 
datetime = structure(c(1466078376.13352, 1466164800, 1466251194.49235, 
1466337600, 1466423992.99026, 1466510400, 1466596853.49096, 
1466683185.13551, 1466769600, 1466856000.06254, 1466942345.50765, 
1467028800, 1467115179.92356, 1467201600, 1467288000, 1467374400, 
1467460801.81376, 1467547200, 1467633604.67316, 1467720000, 
1467806423.20361, 1467892800, 1467979255.99444, 1468065552.68428, 
1468152000, 1468238400, 1468324827.121, 1468411200, 1468497619.36762, 
1468584000, 1468670456.74548, 1468756798.41446, 1468843200, 
1468928779.09091, 1469016500.50633, 1469102400, 1469188805.17385, 
1469275200, 1469361564.70097, 1469448000, 1469534423.82046, 
1469620800, 1469707247.98331, 1469793556.6064, 1469880000, 
1469966391.40473, 1470041370, 1470178341.25, 1470217984.93671
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), year = c(2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), month = c(6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8), day = c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3), hour = c(11.4937413073713, 
11.5, 11.4979137691238, 11.5, 11.4979137691238, 11.5, 11.5146036161335, 
11.4961779013204, 11.5, 11.5003474635163, 11.4853963838665, 
11.5, 11.4940931202224, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5003474635163, 
11.5, 11.5006954102921, 11.5, 11.5066018068103, 11.5, 11.5159944367177, 
11.4867872044506, 11.5, 11.5, 11.5076495132128, 11.5, 11.505211952745, 
11.5, 11.5159944367177, 11.4993045897079, 11.5, 11.2755681818182, 
11.6385372714487, 11.5, 11.5020862308762, 11.5, 11.4895688456189, 
11.5, 11.5066109951287, 11.5, 11.5132127955494, 11.4881780250348, 
11.5, 11.4979137691238, 8.3314447592068, 22.3854166666667, 
9.38818565400844), min = c(29.4777468706537, 29.5, 29.5333796940195, 
29.5, 29.5083449235049, 29.5, 29.5152990264256, 29.4815844336345, 
29.5, 29.4801945795691, 29.4680111265647, 29.5, 29.5198054204309, 
29.5, 29.5, 29.5, 29.5093815149409, 29.5, 29.5361613351878, 
29.5, 29.4906184850591, 29.5, 29.4735744089013, 29.5041724617524, 
29.5, 29.5, 29.4930458970793, 29.5, 29.5100764419736, 29.5, 
29.4860917941586, 29.5152990264256, 29.5, 29.2840909090909, 
29.5295358649789, 29.5, 29.4610570236439, 29.5, 29.5375521557719, 
29.5, 29.500347947112, 29.5, 29.5069541029207, 29.4860917941586, 
29.5, 29.4819193324061, 29.1133144475921, 28.7291666666667, 
29.2911392405063), sec = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30), DOY = c(167.499723767578, 
168.5, 169.499936254057, 170.5, 171.499918868799, 172.5, 
173.500619108329, 174.499827957301, 175.5, 176.500000723882, 
177.499369301499, 178.5, 179.499767633773, 180.5, 181.5, 
182.5, 183.500020992587, 184.5, 185.500054087467, 186.5, 
187.500268560343, 188.5, 189.500648083758, 190.499452364395, 
191.5, 192.5, 193.500313900479, 194.5, 195.500224162227, 
196.5, 197.500656776387, 198.499981648895, 199.5, 200.490498737374, 
201.505792897328, 202.5, 203.500059882553, 204.5, 205.499591446453, 
206.5, 207.50027569976, 208.5, 209.500555362386, 210.499497759233, 
211.5, 212.499900517694, 213.367708333333, 214.953023726852, 
215.41186269339), Day = c(1628.49972376758, 1629.5, 1630.49993625406, 
1631.5, 1632.4999188688, 1633.5, 1634.50061910833, 1635.4998279573, 
1636.5, 1637.50000072388, 1638.4993693015, 1639.5, 1640.49976763377, 
1641.5, 1642.5, 1643.5, 1644.50002099259, 1645.5, 1646.50005408747, 
1647.5, 1648.50026856034, 1649.5, 1650.50064808376, 1651.49945236439, 
1652.5, 1653.5, 1654.50031390048, 1655.5, 1656.50022416223, 
1657.5, 1658.50065677639, 1659.4999816489, 1660.5, 1661.49049873737, 
1662.50579289733, 1663.5, 1664.50005988255, 1665.5, 1666.49959144645, 
1667.5, 1668.50027569976, 1669.5, 1670.50055536239, 1671.49949775923, 
1672.5, 1673.49990051769, 1674.36770833333, 1675.95302372685, 
1676.41186269339), DayH = c(1628.47890588781, 1629.47916666667, 
1630.47907974038, 1631.47916666667, 1632.47907974038, 1633.47916666667, 
1634.47977515067, 1635.47900741256, 1636.47916666667, 1637.47918114431, 
1638.47855818266, 1639.47916666667, 1640.47892054668, 1641.47916666667, 
1642.47916666667, 1643.47916666667, 1644.47918114431, 1645.47916666667, 
1646.4791956421, 1647.47916666667, 1648.47944174195, 1649.47916666667, 
1650.47983310153, 1651.47861613352, 1652.47916666667, 1653.47916666667, 
1654.47948539638, 1655.47916666667, 1656.47938383136, 1657.47916666667, 
1658.47983310153, 1659.47913769124, 1660.47916666667, 1661.46981534091, 
1662.48493905298, 1663.47916666667, 1664.47925359295, 1665.47916666667, 
1666.47873203523, 1667.47916666667, 1668.4794421248, 1669.47916666667, 
1670.47971719981, 1671.47867408438, 1672.47916666667, 1673.47907974038, 
1674.34714353163, 1675.93272569444, 1676.39117440225), DayD = c(1628, 
1629, 1630, 1631, 1632, 1633, 1634, 1635, 1636, 1637, 1638, 
1639, 1640, 1641, 1642, 1643, 1644, 1645, 1646, 1647, 1648, 
1649, 1650, 1651, 1652, 1653, 1654, 1655, 1656, 1657, 1658, 
1659, 1660, 1661, 1662, 1663, 1664, 1665, 1666, 1667, 1668, 
1669, 1670, 1671, 1672, 1673, 1674, 1675, 1676), Sal = c(29.0488087045063, 
29.0242089236389, 28.9704142552782, 28.9337236612778, 28.9124731267455, 
28.8621913531181, 28.7694603506606, 28.6800432876789, 28.6368648858889, 
28.5239238692008, 28.6274684358136, 28.6899766423333, 28.7094982390063, 
28.6427974009653, 28.6540963996528, 28.5762126331528, 28.5617631359555, 
28.6364940399097, 28.6458543031711, 28.603713066875, 28.65796586713, 
28.6926140346389, 28.6470827340195, 28.5985220503964, 28.6620416165972, 
28.6305870582222, 28.7001961730876, 28.6916165265, 28.6656868092356, 
28.8356597378472, 29.266969874235, 28.418354432114, 28.3670879136597, 
28.7002130192898, 28.1320816093038, 27.4618531637569, 27.5341382380668, 
27.4453546479236, 28.2270356746662, 28.3642271282222, 27.9785534427697, 
28.1165695540903, 28.6652365165229, 28.4222878245758, 28.4388172580139, 
28.0149544998192, 28.4748151350047, 28.0933474488542, 27.8804163691308
), Temp = c(-0.902727819368567, -0.824054421545139, -0.720653055488178, 
-0.64214159655, -0.557226600257997, -0.438045884220833, -0.395580348047288, 
-0.295740618513551, -0.262320095793056, -0.160162734756081, 
-0.20336842434701, -0.197846770197222, -0.133355481749131, 
-0.0565102243486111, -0.0215979124673611, 0.125483112529167, 
0.238572840179291, 0.272823149654167, 0.311757436682198, 
0.392257187272917, 0.396628769779013, 0.475891600833333, 
0.607289245171071, 0.644559951482615, 0.665206005440278, 
0.727629137738889, 0.696052211995828, 0.752315860946528, 
0.832433359182071, 0.471555079075, -0.187290608750348, 1.12906111324131, 
1.24940833146181, 0.780415736372869, 2.0088144469993, 2.93373915290972, 
3.19907420429903, 3.16430728506875, 1.87296632160014, 1.74067924683403, 
2.50500692939318, 2.26088904221181, 1.20761122894784, 1.64661297725591, 
1.68971783634167, 2.8011089384096, 1.70051260145987, 2.9201268373125, 
3.38838510550127), Den = c(1023.3705136356, 1023.34875807153, 
1023.30254908484, 1023.27139922778, 1023.25147035396, 1023.20777893194, 
1023.13225399791, 1023.05719108895, 1023.02118660833, 1022.92671791522, 
1023.01148932893, 1023.06187513264, 1023.07546443363, 1023.01910884861, 
1023.02718869861, 1022.95948791944, 1022.94312314663, 1023.00176208264, 
1023.00818908971, 1022.97111798194, 1023.01464410354, 1023.03946157917, 
1022.99742747636, 1022.95676902782, 1023.00684491736, 1022.97892510208, 
1023.03639020376, 1023.02648772361, 1023.00193750904, 1023.15208127222, 
1023.5269599694, 1022.78984692211, 1022.74222825486, 1023.03256159162, 
1022.51158633193, 1021.90175907847, 1021.95317423018, 1021.88198156806, 
1022.59607175591, 1022.71358182847, 1022.35521831037, 1022.47925275556, 
1022.98340138456, 1022.76567206815, 1022.77633019236, 1022.36132367177, 
1022.80426542115, 1022.42016046875, 1022.21591253502), Chl = c(0.426618683276773, 
0.415201663443056, 0.385096423775383, 0.363738871729861, 
0.409404512937413, 0.434480798338889, 0.491604291206537, 
0.464091430292564, 0.519904672929861, 0.549126851486449, 
0.552805036465925, 0.557850158557639, 0.466429236588603, 
0.510509837531944, 0.488934344839583, 0.3889341805625, 0.423089474131341, 
0.499932285390278, 0.459906828269124, 0.365046922974306, 
0.275903841463516, 0.249863925111806, 0.234845544844924, 
0.225590052227399, 0.230629094999306, 0.214579363215278, 
0.166625286886648, 0.171862695222222, 0.188135247756776, 
0.2714899376625, 0.249608510288595, 0.234688186765647, 0.263209856711111, 
0.223578790403409, 0.196086601016174, 0.300936248076389, 
0.198270502905424, 0.254613127958333, 0.211631943366481, 
0.194650132228472, 0.221967901366736, 0.287470503101389, 
0.346767555667594, 0.272033042223922, 0.261851759145139, 
0.30292882953338, 0.354326095381492, 0.139364686395833, 0.25231837455865
), O2 = c(8.40147872631572, 8.38937171346181, 8.41514077121905, 
8.42152294330694, 8.47538879331154, 8.49880474437986, 8.47472190401391, 
8.57655982897498, 8.61944234794514, 8.61577329576095, 8.69213896446314, 
8.68921609862778, 8.69141974274149, 8.70994810763125, 8.68851865927569, 
8.67396664622847, 8.76928090276998, 8.80177919844583, 8.80529066242629, 
8.7617663811118, 8.70471848277554, 8.73156013737708, 8.76644351992003, 
8.7618030795612, 8.79754675150208, 8.79138352644236, 8.75052502651043, 
8.71269655839444, 8.68668315413829, 8.60423627197361, 8.6258442449847, 
8.54381038276356, 8.66501514202014, 8.70410267486577, 8.4057585319121, 
8.04968271129722, 7.92461467095619, 7.9134090372875, 8.41306227992907, 
8.53320737933681, 8.33820448514335, 8.38417834865208, 8.62405400836439, 
8.42477547407102, NaN, 8.40141680898052, 8.48576496565722, 
8.28582430035417, 7.96892147137215), ID = c(1.21133857408067, 
1.16902903935, 1.11473135400904, 1.07275230797986, 1.03223155043115, 
0.995775405476389, 0.962935072082058, 0.91925791728214, 0.844455992659028, 
0.791515976553162, 0.751516800569541, 0.702131858139583, 
0.707145974122307, 0.599273624570139, 0.502570098100694, 
0.347712868368056, 0.335673459499653, 0.152877532414716, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PAR = c(23.0673615360132, 
32.1793662073708, 6.5780126555751, 26.73609441565, 48.6703905053255, 
31.0519168669979, 32.4282362099165, 62.9277536311577, 42.349564172909, 
36.1037009880507, 36.4754793940695, 41.2935785894486, 56.3411955151001, 
32.0717618120021, 68.055826105709, 83.7724642720521, 92.4702250095455, 
63.3510742622049, 123.118356252679, 127.241395072853, 134.184346299723, 
144.712733899262, 152.801023269344, 145.640278660995, 149.976623338179, 
159.125758044126, 185.67869649515, 154.650267769035, 118.350412925882, 
97.6856430502583, 120.50500187914, 114.336144557309, 113.572030429865, 
164.301402493774, 129.582420528291, 116.032838587456, 129.230413097896, 
74.3598830959583, 156.888302579191, 146.709144185685, 170.418761938188, 
109.206260157938, 107.575876383898, 116.456387998532, 101.787857506992, 
138.683838377278, 59.2571219263966, 301.257992689583, 132.693163343932
), CO2 = c(313.287072418802, 316.458148259666, 311.875193224513, 
310.725188107302, 307.113608999861, 305.345432183449, 306.866938424095, 
296.338500576548, 301.685137467594, 301.496499046973, 292.31953961727, 
288.615012611822, 290.213867048504, 285.695949347705, 287.207517193185, 
288.916130984771, 284.025547924356, 280.331734920028, 276.455368840947, 
283.035881080528, 288.114431753027, 281.591903017038, 277.471364486351, 
275.133554284401, 272.650852387413, 276.396523718707, 279.08769762117, 
282.910516518289, 287.561712111621, 298.595955828581, 290.299065880292, 
280.221814783983, 271.902607398331, 267.655275534974, 187.578839181691, 
295.344229054242, 294.793103994916, 299.124436790682, 275.716171689137, 
271.748266282198, 274.022120842021, 276.591247188178, 268.405941518524, 
267.118504699234, 265.624798023783, 275.240563041295, 266.857200690445, 
79.6423144553947, 283.663994869992), IR = c(94.888329799096, 
168.205345239028, 43.6012952622392, 155.376871086389, 249.315080590056, 
188.485805169097, 140.05749463426, 327.30331523419, 317.749437070833, 
335.839690080959, 288.73672165751, 315.9134794, 342.093960744267, 
147.913321086785, 265.198319784722, 299.562780926042, 349.640961553857, 
170.956328942361, 328.451052432198, 347.751372498958, 334.37511897533, 
334.446311627778, 329.363355990612, 326.623001649513, 322.837199274444, 
322.997446772569, 325.385474717316, 280.920902051319, 190.673680428353, 
126.069364682462, 163.4228148, 153.172728333727, 166.565107412222, 
251.82414954041, 241.950038763854, 186.326751968743, 252.239057356328, 
114.703921665806, 231.317110343331, 217.123805467431, 263.428218097425, 
150.468188479832, 152.846154624771, 164.441859235949, 149.983140035384, 
190.64123323394, 86.6026193321907, 449.640322291667, 216.572470091966
), Wind = c(1.98109184856853, 4.53879830464599, 8.70032103138219, 
6.59899662613967, 2.86950158330462, 1.91094036908824, 2.49644956157983, 
4.51135762214745, 2.42873628334266, 1.82804668840925, 2.79143010703083, 
2.16237533031289, 2.15848082990616, 2.82829126926611, 3.04592042806289, 
4.43295455205038, 3.64900015248738, 5.93927428289323, 4.568747849922, 
4.15613471303208, 2.91637168187178, 2.52179220100977, 1.44870759127444, 
1.39712269197199, 2.07052311200698, 3.19886056692388, 4.59176673645728, 
4.23987138922819, 6.5241126458074, 7.15729601227273, 5.78232411651958, 
4.8622789499446, 4.40757803569404, 6.01049680807786, 4.37623822535244, 
5.64634072332915, 6.9869768911053, 6.16325833892184, 4.01858391688531, 
5.13520196430042, 4.98398472755042, 5.54085930760014, 6.1472408154439, 
2.8608028792402, 3.73845798467388, 4.77812324101398, 2.78512103174882, 
3.31994465129167, 2.24169682706943), AirTemp = c(4.40810744394993, 
4.83240431381944, 2.53433683929068, 3.31246568041667, 3.30829270725313, 
5.59009755125, 5.59340448650904, 7.34151981681723, 7.95149346486111, 
6.35076665670605, 9.06164061349096, 10.7704471338194, 10.8565160628214, 
7.49149095395833, 8.37798674340278, 6.50827215368056, 5.0225399762335, 
7.40747958826389, 9.64073649255911, 9.69248163631944, 12.3917031494788, 
14.0608254371528, 15.2186511161335, 17.322914922114, 17.6249810152778, 
17.0803095690972, 15.2016485305981, 13.1528769309028, 12.8485860753996, 
9.93430037097222, 8.49772086689847, 9.2253200445758, 7.55898443965278, 
7.24284858572443, 6.94021240464135, 5.91370547875, 4.38009589235049, 
5.42976892055556, 7.28829746376912, 6.63289298236111, 6.79095412268615, 
9.45812934520833, 9.2179658081363, 10.4900065421419, 9.56056064826389, 
10.5006926291377, 9.92910989490085, 11.8657420520833, 11.0606573877637
), Press = c(1010.94713220445, 1000.91298554167, 987.981428212796, 
1003.31839191667, 1010.80608631433, 1010.70622420833, 1014.20480271905, 
1018.25909922168, 1017.2977571875, 1017.2116500139, 1014.43729111961, 
1016.86667607639, 1017.77638776233, 1017.73254004861, 1017.58831039583, 
1023.96083316667, 1023.37822454482, 1018.61740789583, 1017.69460385953, 
1019.06393609722, 1019.70283468381, 1021.57185751389, 1022.54906664812, 
1019.93420589013, 1015.60680218056, 1013.92687847222, 1018.10282961752, 
1017.75759179861, 1011.06972191105, 1000.6753998125, 1006.33157139777, 
1010.47605901252, 1004.2360214375, 1003.47128640625, 1005.9544021519, 
1002.94591790972, 998.129144311544, 994.845405819444, 996.572536383866, 
1007.62132047917, 1015.58149314544, 1015.31391086806, 1014.80282973574, 
1014.86646130737, 1011.12184847917, 1007.64412461752, 1008.94791512748, 
1016.38731552083, 1014.23599833755), Ts = c(0.0939091805522304, 
0.0933571324389885, 0.0926315816934272, 0.0920807064972713, 
0.0914849244286843, 0.0906487390808381, 0.0903508008513881, 
0.0896503398391888, 0.0894158788365697, 0.0886992027701387, 
0.089002314704399, 0.0889635640417059, 0.0885111330762104, 
0.0879720536464657, 0.0877271381692247, 0.0866953766257083, 
0.0859020961040837, 0.0856618525704464, 0.0853887527876392, 
0.0848241204226848, 0.0847934498305695, 0.0842374892345861, 
0.0833158824031102, 0.0830544806008765, 0.0829096777186984, 
0.0824718703347108, 0.0826933403725865, 0.0822988121621235, 
0.0817369399215142, 0.0842685237873781, 0.0888896196011912, 
0.079656634577284, 0.0788127760214962, 0.0821017792323535, 
0.0734881871639127, 0.0670067820465301, 0.065144627947714, 
0.0653888659545473, 0.0744405166847922, 0.0753679790243025, 
0.0700098285152706, 0.0717215346483428, 0.0791058326941815, 
0.0760274126969679, 0.0757251777215326, 0.0679345115120072, 
0.0756495928144236, 0.0670994071000443, 0.0638174503450037
), C = c(8.94065543989075, 8.91870846791228, 8.89129215782166, 
8.87041424509199, 8.84686764433126, 8.81516998854457, 8.8084814071784, 
8.78498979939825, 8.77801254243485, 8.75556135353215, 8.76169863848835, 
8.75623839427317, 8.73659381953759, 8.71875839369915, 8.7081454153551, 
8.67125827547341, 8.64042586696951, 8.62643884773293, 8.61505698749588, 
8.59531077426103, 8.59085475620887, 8.56693513415321, 8.53362826949292, 
8.5263455666875, 8.51701535738585, 8.50192437544613, 8.50643587795999, 
8.49224025025525, 8.47229959883608, 8.56396191736222, 8.71907216880554, 
8.40708575426135, 8.37898781319225, 8.48450883536676, 8.19834292777621, 
8.02742642860397, 7.94335742141408, 7.96038019864108, 8.22636890956846, 
8.25191633282365, 8.08596024446269, 8.14084822127661, 8.37247267374788, 
8.27175018847621, 8.25980001007453, 8.01532360653014, 8.25581090260999, 
7.97597778883369, 7.87850954070042), deltaO = c(-0.539176713575035, 
-0.529336754450473, -0.476151386602607, -0.448891301785048, 
-0.371478851019715, -0.316365244164706, -0.333759503164495, 
-0.20842997042327, -0.158570194489716, -0.139788057771207, 
-0.0695596740252039, -0.0670222956453951, -0.0451740767961, 
-0.00881028606789499, -0.0196267560794031, 0.00270837075506498, 
0.12885503580047, 0.1753403507129, 0.190233674930407, 0.166455606850779, 
0.11386372656667, 0.164625003223876, 0.23281525042711, 0.235457512873693, 
0.280531394116234, 0.289459150996232, 0.244089148550445, 
0.22045630813919, 0.214383555302208, 0.0402743546113934, 
-0.0932279238208418, 0.136724628502207, 0.286027328827889, 
0.219593839499005, 0.207415604135885, 0.0222562826932507, 
-0.0187427504578891, -0.0469711613535759, 0.18669337036061, 
0.281291046513154, 0.25224424068066, 0.243330127375477, 0.251581334616514, 
0.153326651891512, NaN, 0.285793738567012, 0.229954063047229, 
0.30984651152048, 0.0904119306717343), k = c(1.3843960648632, 
6.67024147531018, 21.4898676969447, 12.6511158639218, 2.86455163396347, 
1.18964832218751, 2.48536575543307, 6.11457188358869, 2.22117060425211, 
1.39709711243724, 3.15681260593466, 1.69087035092879, 1.96031515063071, 
3.05646023068449, 3.88091903012736, 5.89522588325253, 4.61191456284459, 
9.9876497231258, 5.87859816406069, 5.25567516554151, 2.66410131584561, 
1.91750845984603, 0.912508517423828, 0.788437993630362, 1.51297375451523, 
4.1010391646833, 6.69386108760172, 6.60202002300452, 15.3120378300758, 
17.0865393002387, 10.0683520284002, 7.04605349774694, 7.06555793241213, 
11.2155892631143, 6.95932652757971, 10.5460039186381, 14.4457642190408, 
11.1713965641408, 5.13491665227681, 9.17952853060783, 7.55395359942885, 
9.93963153178716, 10.7556273136677, 2.74976182917367, 4.24852415082047, 
7.44862825836769, 2.51232305022297, 3.16831051334729, 1.58255842462718
), NCP = c(-6555.51823916664, -30259.5423200574, -93284.1485540249, 
-52785.5627897263, -9203.47328702618, -3474.14113092716, 
-6643.58632076862, -11084.7222504768, -2779.86321684949, 
-1481.582285219, -1974.24446012626, -1018.46398725869, -689.919166266737, 
1680.8563208385, -442.391803921574, -180.816469873293, 5330.66701930139, 
16192.8444708129, 10544.1353158852, 8370.10647897766, 2991.63246971473, 
2741.5747232174, 1716.98452107368, 1723.27625157814, 3806.41762190115, 
10674.6146528716, 15783.1240720338, 14337.3594334794, 30669.7204136871, 
3257.08033198347, -8574.53718630027, 10409.6993939132, 17974.5471722579, 
22284.8034527993, 11849.079774671, 7706.03700970845, 2652.66574996729, 
-10421.7431381603, 8448.71926418016, 24212.1390873852, 18754.1407791307, 
21358.338661014, 22616.1137584938, 3695.2416322836, NaN, 
18437.8290676373, 4903.94862723591, 8770.18358118303, 1206.37283774814
)), .Names = c("Group.1", "datetime", "year", "month", "day", 
"hour", "min", "sec", "DOY", "Day", "DayH", "DayD", "Sal", "Temp", 
 "Den", "Chl", "O2", "ID", "PAR", "CO2", "IR", "Wind", "AirTemp", 
"Press", "Ts", "C", "deltaO", "k", "NCP"), row.names = 1324:1372, class 
= "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output you are looking for is that subset of `df` rows having maximum or minimum `Temp` among all rows with the same `month` value then:

```
subset(df, ave(Temp, month, FUN = function(x) x %in% range(x)) == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck - that worked perfectly! Very concise.